# Aircraft models

Tags: data-request, transportation

Where can I find an overview of as many aircraft models as possible, preferably commercial passenger and cargo aircrafts?

I'm interested in this data, or as much data as possible:

- Model name (ex: Boeing 747-400)
- Manufactured from/to
- Possible seating/class configurations
- Cruising speed and max speed
- Fuel capacity
- Fuel consumption per ... (any unit)
- Minimum takeoff distance
- Minimum landing distance

Etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being unable to find the data I requested myself, I created a Google Docs Spreadsheet [for anyone to view](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fsjVEjL1stMabaOptBOw0cBlV9Vt8fv00TeLwVgs5wo/edit?usp=sharing) which holds most of the data I'm interested in for a "handful" of planes. If you are interested in adding to the spreadsheet, or help me keep the data updated, feel free to contact me.

It currently contains about 150 items, with the following properties:

- Type
- Name
- PassengerCapacity
- Range
- MaxSpeed
- FuelEconomy
- FuelCapacity
- MaxPayload
- MinLandingDistance
- MaxTakeoffDistance

Comment: Would you mind adding license information? For instance add "Public domain" just after the "metric units" header. Cheers!

Comment: Of course. Anyone can steal this information; it only took me a day to collect. :)

Answer (score 1):

This site has specs for about 400 commercial aircraft. But you will have to parse each spec manually. No data dump that I saw

http://www.airliners.net/aircraft-data/

The data can not really be called open though: "*The information in this database is copyright protected and may not be copied or used in any way without proper permission.*"